PrematureCloseException in netty http client
We are using Spring Cloud Gateway (spring boot 2.7.X, JDK 11) to route request. To fetch/pass OAuth2.0 token before routing, filter is added to fetch it from OAuth2.0 provider, to make secure call to endpoint.
Most of the time the POST (reactive call) is successful, but in certain cases when there is say a gap of couple of hours between messages/request, at client end (spring cloud gateway) we are getting below exception while calling the URL for getting token post authorization, resulting in failure to send payload.
    Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response; nested exception is reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST 
 *******.com/auth2/token

Basically I am using spring 'OAuth2AuthorizedClient' instance (from reactive manager) in filter reactively to access the token (it is supposed to cached until expiry as well).
Trying to understand the root cause of why it could be happening in above use case and is there any setting/configuration can be done to mitigate it? Thanks
Any suggestion on how it can be reproduced ?
